# How to get action of @WebMethod in JAX-WS service implementation?

Tags: java, web-services

I am implementing a service interface in Java which was generated using JAX-WS RI 2.2.8.

I have following lines:

```
@WebService(name = "IService", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface IService {

@WebMethod(operationName = "PersonList", action = "http://tempuri.org/IService/PersonList")
@WebResult(name = "PersonListResult", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/")
@RequestWrapper(localName = "PersonList", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", className = "org.test.wsdl.PersonList")
@ResponseWrapper(localName = "PersonListResponse", targetNamespace = "http://tempuri.org/", className = "org.test.wsdl.PersonListResponse")
public PersonListResponseX personList();
```

What i want to do, I want to get this:

action = **"http://tempuri.org/IService/PersonList"**)

And to use it in my Service implementation's SoapActionCallback.

```
@Service
public class NewService implements IService {

private final ObjectFactory of = new ObjectFactory();

@Autowired
private WebServiceTemplate webServiceTemplate;

@Override
public PersonListResponseX personList() {

// URL I need is http://tempuri.org/IService/PersonList
    SoapActionCallback callback = new SoapActionCallback(URL);
    PersonList personList = of.createPersonList();

    PersonListResponse personListResponse = (PersonListResponse) webServiceTemplate.marshalSendAndReceive(personList, callback);
    JAXBElement<PersonListResponseX> value = personListResponse.getPersonListResult();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    WebMethod webmethod = <Soap class Here>.class.getAnnotation(WebMethod.class);
    String action = webmethod.action();
```

Comment: You might want to add some detail as to why this is the correct answer.